# Prefer matches that have multiple hits?

Tags: helm

It seems that `helm` prefers shorter paths when ordering the current set of matches. Is there a way to keep this general behavior but also take the number of matches into account?

In the screenshot I am searching for `generator block` and would prefer to have `client/src/app/shared/block/generator/generator.ts` as first hit because it contains two occurences of `generator`.

[image: Seems that shorter hits are preferred]